# Generate Alphanumeric ID from Numeric ID in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic MySQL database where each row is assigned a unique incrementing ID number, however I would also like each row to have a unique 6 character, alpha numeric ID which also increments. Example:

```
Row 1: ID = 1, Name = AAAAAA
Row 2: ID = 2, Name = AAAAAB
Row 3: ID = 3, Name = AAAAAC
```

The database is added to via PHP so this can be done through PHP as well as through pure SQL.

So far I have been trying to build a PHP function which could turn the Numeric ID into the AlphaNumeric ID to no success.

Anybody have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you had tried? Depending on your solution, you may be too far off but at least we may be able to locate your mistake and correct it.

Comment: The function itself wasn't much, it really just divided the given Numeric ID by 36 (26 Letters, 10 Numbers) and then I was trying to work out a way to then break down what was after the decimal point into A-Z/0-9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work and produce unique ID's (produces just letters):

```
function alphaID($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return str_pad($r, 6, 'A', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo alphaID(0); // returns "AAAAAA"
echo alphaID(1); // returns "AAAAAB"
...
echo alphaID(8652); // returns "AAALTU"
```

Comment: MD5 wont produce an incremented value so that after 10 inserts you have something like AAAAAJ

Comment: @ITroubs, that's true, missed the part where he required it to be incrementing. But it'll still generate unique values. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an way to have it incrementing, like AAAAAA, AAAAAB, AAAAAC etc

Comment: @Jamza, and that's what the first example is for. I've revised my answer a bit.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the code (my bad). That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

The numeric id is unique. I wouldn't store the alphanumeric value in the table (it violates a few rules of DB normalization) and besides the numeric id and the alphanumeric id are actually the same value, no sense double storing a value! If possible (and it should be), only ever query using the numeric  value (which I assume is your primary key anyways).

I would use a PHP function to convert numeric to alphanumeric (such as posted by Tatu Ulmanen) and call it in your pages when you have a reason to display the alphanumeric. In MSSQL you could write a UDF to display the value whenever it was needed if you didn't want to rely on the PHP. Though I never really got into stored functions etc with myssql so not sure if its possible to do that with it.

You could also use PHP's base_convert() function

```
base_convert(35, 10, 36); //= convert '35' from base '10' to base '36' and you would get 'Z'
```

Comment: yep. I was about to reply the same. the overhead here its minimum.

Answer (score 1):

an easy way would b to represent the number in a base-32 or hexadecimal format... an easy and a quick fix...

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it the hard way and first making a char column primary and then doing a ton insert rigger that looks up a global variable for the current maximal alphanumeric value and increments that and afterwards assigns the incremented value to the new inserted line. The problem is i don't if there is already a special string incrementation function or if you have to make some casts from string to integers then increment the integers and afterwards do a back cast to string.

Comment: or do it on the script side, like in Tatu Ulmanen's answer but be careful. this can get pretty messy if make any new code working on the same table and you forget to use that function.